# Templates and higher-order kinds in C++

Tags: c++, templates, higher-kinded-types

I am trying to write a function that takes two containers of the same contained type, e.g., two `std::vector<int>`s, or a `std::list<int>` and a `std::vector<int>`. (But not a `std::vector<int>` and a `std::vector<double>`!)

Since I am not quite sure regarding how it should be done, I decided to write a test progam first:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>

struct vector_wrapper
{
  template <typename T>
  struct instance_wrapper
  {
    typedef typename std::vector<T> instance;
  };
};

struct list_wrapper
{
  template <typename T>
  struct instance_wrapper
  {
    typedef typename std::list<T> instance;
  };
};

template <typename T, typename C1, typename C2>
void move(typename C1::instance_wrapper<T>::instance& c1, typename C2::instance_wrapper<T>::instance& c2) // line 29
{
  while (c1.size() > 0)
  {
    c2.push_front(c1.back());
    c1.pop_back();
  }
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::list  <int> l;

  v.reserve(10);
  for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

  move<int, vector_wrapper, list_wrapper>(v, l);

  std::for_each(l.begin(), l.end(),
    [] (int i) { std::cout << i << " "; }
  );

  std::cout << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

---

This code gives me the following compile-time error with g++ 4.7, using the `-std=c++11` flag:

```
metaclass.cpp:29:24: error: non-template 'instance_wrapper' used as template
... more ...
```

Why does the compiler not correctly identify `instance_wrapper` as a template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Compiler has already told you what is wrong (errors from [ideone](http://ideone.com/RHJsp)):

> prog.cpp:25:24: error: non-template 'instance_wrapper' used as template
>   prog.cpp:25:24: note: use 'C1::template instance_wrapper' to indicate that it is a template

Use `C1::template instance_wrapper` instead of `C1::instance_wrapper` - and, similarly, do the same for `C2::instance_wrapper`:

```
template <typename T, typename C1, typename C2>
void move(typename C1::template instance_wrapper<T>::instance& c1, 
    typename C2::template instance_wrapper<T>::instance& c2)
{
    // ...
```

It's because `C1` is template and compiler cannot deduce that `instance_wrapper` is template and treats it as non-template type.

**Please, please, read *everything* compiler outputs.** Not just line-by-line. Often compiler says what's wrong in one of previous or following lines, as in this case, when it's already giving you the answer!

Comment: I never ever knew about having to insert `template` in the middle of that. I guess everyday you learn something! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a better solution that doesn't require any weird wrappers that disable argument deduction and have the client specify them, just clean and simple SFINAE that works in C++03:

```
#include <type_traits> // or Boost equivalent

// a little helper struct to keep the 
// function as clutter-free as possible
template<class C1, class C2, class T = void>
struct enable_if_same_value_type
  : std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename C1::value_type,
        typename C2::value_type>::value, T>
{
};

template<class C1, class C2>
typename enable_if_same_value_type<C1, C2>::type
move(C1& source, C2& target){
  /* ... */
}
```

Note that your code isn't quite generic, btw, since `push_front` is not supported by `std::vector`, so you're never able to pass two of them. Also, I wouldn't call the function `move`, since you're prepending the content of the first container on the second.

That said, there's a `std::move` overload in C++11 that takes three iterators and moves the content marked by the first too into the output iterator that is passed as the third parameter. As such, your `main` can be rewritten as follows:

```
#include <algorithm> // algorithmic move
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <iterator> // front_inserter
#include <iostream>

int main(){
  std::vector<int> v;
  std::list<int> l;

  v.reserve(10);
  for (unsigned i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

  // I used 'rbegin'  and 'rend' so the order stays the same
  std::move(v.rbegin(), v.rend(), std::front_inserter(l));

  std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/Jfs0C)

Comment: You don't need the extra struct, you can do `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<typename C1::value_type, typename C2::value_type>::value>::type move(...) { ... }`

Comment: @Seth: The struct is just there for a cleaner look. Moved the SFINAE to the return type, though.

Comment: Regarding `enable_if`: this kind of weirdness is precisely what pushed (and, to be honest, continues to push me) towards Haskell. Also, my `move` function was not meant to be a `std::move` overload, I simply chose the function's name in an unwise manner.

Comment: @Eduardo: I was only talking about the naming, nothing in relation to `std::move`. I was talking about a `std::move` overload, because there's the iterator one int `<algorithm>`, and the move semantics one in `<utility>`.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference, you can do this more simply:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename A1, typename A2, template <typename, typename> class Cont1, template<typename, typename> class Cont2>
void move(Cont1<T, A1>& from, Cont2<T, A2>& to) {
    while (!from.empty()) { // use !empty(), not size()
        to.push_front(from.back());
        from.pop_back();
    }
}

std::vector<int> v;
std::list<int> l;

move(v, l); // and no need to specify types
```

Comment: `std::queue`, `std::stack` and `std::(unordered_)(multi){map, set}` would like a word with you. :P

Comment: @Xeo meh, no one cares about them.

Comment: Aswell as all the user-defined containers that don't just have two template parameter *\*looking over to Boost**.

Comment: @Xeo yeah, your way is better for that reason (and others).

Comment: I found this out, like, 15 minutes after accepting the first answer. Actually, for this to work elegantly, this needs a couple of typedef templates: http://ideone.com/WWViC . Also, this answer needs more upvotes.